# tela de loading aparece so o ícone sobre o conteúdo

Tags: javascript, html, css, load

minha tela de loading aparece só o icone sobre o conteúdo da tela inicial. quero adicionar uma cor solida ao fundo que desaparece junto com o icone quando o site carregar. como adiciono?

```
<body onload = "function()">
      <div class="load">
         <img src="images/logo-gif.gif">
      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript ">
        window.onload = function() {
            window.addEventListener("onload ", function() {
                $('.load').show();
            });
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.load').hide();
            }, 700);
        }
     </script>
 </body>
```

css:

```
.load {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 45%;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Pra isso acontecer você precisa fazer com que a classe **.load** esteja com **width:100%** e **height:100vh**. e com isso vc define a cor e a opacidade do fundo e a imagem centralizada.

```css
.load {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 5s;
}

.load img {
  margin-top: 50%;
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<body onload="function()">
  <div class="load">
    <img src="https://media.tenor.com/8ZhQShCQe9UAAAAC/loader.gif">
  </div>

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      window.addEventListener("onload ", function() {
        $('.load').show();
      });
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.load').hide();
      }, 700);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).